# Some unicode is being stripped from file and folder names when created

Tags: unicode, box-api

I've got a filename that has a character U1F607 (SMILING FACE WITH HALO) in it.

I create the file using the V2 API (and also directly on the website) and the result is that the character is stripped from the filename.

The problem I'm having is that I have a function like this:

```
path = "foldername \xf0\x9f\x98\x87"
folder.find( :type => 'folder', :name => path, :recursive => false ).first ||
  folder.create_folder( path )
```

The first time through, the `find` fails, and the folder is created as `"foldername "`.  The second time through, the `find` fails again, and strangely an additional folder named `"foldername "` is created.

My questions are these:

- Is silently stripping the characters an intended part of the API? (As opposed to returning a 406 Not Acceptable)
- Is there a list of allowed/disallowed characters that can be replicated in API clients.
- Why are there two folders of the same name being created?

Comment: Apparently the stripping is happening after the duplicate folder/filename detection, because ordinarily duplicate filenames are rejected with a Box::Api::NameTaken exception.

Answer (score 0):

We are rolling out more character support this week.  It should start just working within a day or two as it gets rolled out.

Comment: As of August 7th, this is still a problem.

I think one of the issues might be that this particular character, isn't really a character that you'd expect to see supported.  its "SMILING FACE WITH HALO".

I think the thing that needs to be solved here is that folder.find() isn't stripping out the invalid characters in the same way (or at all) that Box is on their backend.

Is there a list of valid unicode codepoints that box accepts?